# How to grab a key value no matter where it's located in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Grab this **slice_type: section**. No matter where it's in the array,
     so here its [1], but it could be [0] or [2]. in the end I need to grab the items key that are in the object that has slice_type: 'section';

```
  [ { slice_type: 'structure',
        slice_label: null,
        items: [ [Object] ],
        primary: {} },
      { slice_type: 'section', << Grab this slice_type section. No matter where it's in the array,
 so here its [1], but it could be [0] or [2]. in the end I need to grab the items key that are in the object that has slice_type: 'section';
        slice_label: null,
        items:
         [ [Object],
           [Object],
           [Object],
           [Object],
           [Object],
           [Object],
           [Object] ], <<- get this array of values
        primary: { headline: [Array] } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter and map array functions.

```
let result = arrays
.filter((obj) => obj["slice_type"] === "section") // filter by condition
.map(obj => obj.items);// return items of objects in filtered list
```

Answer (score 0):

because it an array and have object inside it
so you can loop all object and check for `slice_type`
For instance:

```
let listOfSliceType = []
for (let object of array) {
     if (object['slice_type'] && object['slice_type'] === 'section') {
          listOfSliceType.push(object);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to filter your array and grab your items:

```
var objects = myArray.filter(obj => {
  return obj.slice_type === 'section'
});

var result = objects[0].items;
```